# hbase java code returns null for a get but hbase shell get comman returns record

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I have just started using hbase and also not a proficient java programmer. I created a debug program to test the current hbase program that does put & get records and also as a deduping mechanism. The debug program checks to see if certain ids are present in the hbase table that should have been inserted using the other program. When I do a get, for the most part records are there but some will be returned as null (not found). When I manually check from the hbase shell and request the same id, it returns the row with timestamp. Is there something I am not understanding here? Are there multiple versions of a record kept in hbase?  I assumed hbase made unique records based on the id provided.

```
// code to get record
public static byte[] getPreHbase(String provid, String commentId) throws IOException  {
        provid = "98";
        commentId = commentId.trim();
        String rec = provid + "." + commentId;
        byte [] value= "test".getBytes();

        try{
          Get g = new Get(Bytes.toBytes(rec));  
          Result r = htableII.get(g);
          value = r.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("cmmnttest"),Bytes.toBytes("cmmntposts"));
          String valueStr = Bytes.toString(value);



        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return value;
```

As I mentioned this is only sometimes for some ids while others are returned. This is the manual call in shell

```
get 'hb_test', '98.1010000000003_1asdfghjkl'

COLUMN                                   CELL
 cmmnttest:cmmntposts                    timestamp=1420659812914,   
 value=   1010000000003_1asdfghjkl
   1 row(s) in 0.0140 seconds
```